# ¿Como puedo acceder al valor de una cookie fuera de la instancia de ExpressJS?

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy intentado obtener el valor de una cookie pero fuera de la instancia de Express, usando el objeto 'request'

```
const user = app.request.cookies.user
console.log(user)
```

Pero me dice que la propiedad 'user' no esta definida y me crashea la aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `Request` de `express` es una extensión de la clase `ClientRequest` del módulo `http` de node (tal y como lo indican en [su documentación](https://expressjs.com/es/4x/api.html#req)):

> The req object is an enhanced version of Node’s own request object and supports all built-in fields and methods.

En dicho módulo, tenemos el método [`ClientRequest#getHeader( )`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_getheader_name), que nos devuelve el contenido de una cabecera de la solicitud.

Ahora, buscamos la cabecera adecuada ... ¡ bingo !, es la cabecera [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie).

Pues listo, ya lo tenemos:

```
const user = app.request.getHeader( 'Cookie' );
console.log( user );
```

Comment: Al final lo hice una forma mas diferente, creando un variable global `const cookies = {}` y pasando los valores de `req.cookies` a esa variable. algo así `app.use((req, res, next) => { cookies = req.cookies; next() })` y funcionó

Comment: Pues entonces **no marques** esta respuesta como `la que usé`. Y no deberías puntuarla si no la probaste. ¿ Y si está mal ? Deberías *auto-responderte* para que otros sepan como hacerlo.

Comment: Tu respuesta es acertada, funciona, solo que tengo que analizar las cookies, para crear un objeto con los datos de cada cookie.